# Setting javacc to work with command prompt

Tags: java, path, javacc

I've been trying to set up javacc but am having problems. When I type javacc adder.jj (in the directory where adder.jj is) I am getting "'javacc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

To my understanding I have to go to environmental variables, TEMP and change PATH to have C:\javacc-6.0\bin; added to the start. (I extracted the javacc zip to C:). I have tried this and restarted my computer with no luck. I also tried adding C:\javacc-6.0\bin\lib but again no luck. I did this when I installed java to get cmd to recognise javac and it worked!

This is probably trivial but I just can't get it to work!

Thank you

Henry

Comment: From that article I got two things: first include the path which is inconvenient and for me didn't work. Or make the path permanent by adding it to system variables which from my question you can see I have tried. I hope you don't think I'm skimping research, forums are usually my last resort. http://i.imgur.com/XGNJo5U.png

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In the version [6.0](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/download/javacc-6.0.zip) the `bin` directory is missing the scripts which run `javacc`. That is why you are getting the error from the windows command prompt.

What you have is a jar file `javacc.jar` located in the lib directory. All you need is to add that jar file to your `classpath` and run the `java.exe` and pass the main class which runs `javacc`, the later happens to be named `javacc` too, so to run `javacc` just proceed like this:

```
cmd>  java -cp C:\javacc-6.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc
```

In the latest version they seem to have forgotten to add the scripts in the `bin` folder of the package. You can download [version 5.0](https://java.net/projects/javacc/downloads/download/javacc-5.0.zip), it containes all the script files you need, among others a file with the name `javacc.bat`, this is the one the window commad prompt is looking for and not finding in your case.

Of course, you can just copy those scripts from the `5.0` version to the `bin` directory of the `6.0` version, they will also work. and since you already have set the path to contain `C:\javacc-6.0\bin` then you can run it like you have tried before, without closing the command prompt window or even restarting your whole computer!

**Edit - new links**

The links above are unfortunately no longer valid, luckily the content has been moved to [github](https://github.com/). here the new links:

Project url:  https://javacc.org/

Project url on github: https://javacc.github.io/javacc/

Earlier versions: https://github.com/javacc/javacc/branches/

Comment: Downgraded to version 5.0 worked a dream. Since I am starting out with javacc I can't see having a slighter older version being a problem. But thanks for the information for when I feel like upgrading to 6!

edit: Just seen your edit, would of been easier but I'll just work with 5.0 Thanks again!

Comment: To sum it up. Download javacc-6.0 then go to the command line and type in cmd. So if I have a .jj file I can do this. `java-cp C:\Users\me\Downloads\javacc-6.0\javacc-6.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc C:\Users\me\FileIWantToRun.jj`

Comment: @StreamingBits exactly! Or to avoid typing it each time, create your own `javacc.bat` file with the following content `java-cp C:\Users\me\Downloads\javacc-6.0\javacc-6.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc %1` and call it like this `javacc.bat C:\Users\me\FileIWantToRun.jj` (.bat is optional since if omitted windows cmd searches for executables with the extensions listed in the environment variable `PATHEXT` (type in cmd `echo %PATHEXT%` to see what are those)).

Comment: The link is dead(

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

- Download version 5.0, copy the files that come in the bin folder, except the lib folder (they are `.bat files`)
- Paste those files in the same location, but in version 6.0 and resolved issue.

The error is that they did not add the executables in the bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

1. open cmd
2. cd to the directory where the javacc (calculator_2.jj) file loacted
3. type in the cmd  **java -cp D:\S2018\CS661\javacc-6.0\javacc-6.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc calculator_2.jj**